# Confused about " create a Label widget as a child to the root window"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

***Here is something I saw (note the red line):***

[image]

***But when I check the Tkinter module, I saw this:***

[image]

**So, does it mean that the 'root' argument** (in the example above)  **is passed to the 'master' parameter** (in the example below)  ?

I'm using python 2

Comment: Yes, the root argument is passed to the master parameter. Does this clear up your confusion? If not, please provide more detail.

Comment: Please stop posting **pictures of text** - write it out, correctly formatted, and provide a proper attribution. See e.g http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284577/3001761

Comment: @Kevin  then what does the master do? from where can I find out what does the master do?

Answer (score 1):

> So, does it mean that the 'root' argument (in the example above) is passed to the 'master' parameter (in the example below) ?

That is correct.

This tells Tkinter which element you want to place the new one under.

In this example you are placing the `Label()` `w` into Tkinter's `root()` window.

Here is an example where we create a `Frame()` in `root()` and put a `Label()` and a `Button()` into that `Frame()`:

```
root = Tk()
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_label = Label(my_frame, text='Hello World')
my_button = Button(my_frame, text='Button!')

my_frame.pack()
my_label.pack()
my_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: then what does the master do? from where can I find out what does the master do?

Comment: @walkerlala `master` tells Tkinter which element to put the new widget into.  `Label(master=root, text='Hello')` is the same thing.